# Outlook 2010 Rule is performing only the move action, and skipping all others

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

The rule is triggered by my being a CC and specific text in the Subject. It appears the rule executes all actions ONLY one the most recent message with the same From:, To:, CC: and Subject. Is Conversation processing the culprit? These are not actually conversations but automated messages. What can I do to get all actions performed on all these messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of the rules in "Manage rules and alerts" to put the move action last.